# How to change package name to lower case on Google console?

Tags: console, package

I have published an app on Google playstore but later realized that I needed to have the package name in lower case, so the name is still the same, only lowercased. But it seems the console picks it as different, meaning it is case sensitive. is there any way I can rectify this without having to publish it as a new app?

Comment: can you provide some printscreens?

Comment: I'm not sure what printscreens are those because the issue is about renaming the package name to lower case from uppercase on Google developer console, I don't want to publish a new app.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue,
DataBinding does not work with my package name because it has upper letters.
My App is already published on google play.
So
I changed package name upper letters to small letters in all project and in namespace
But
 I left only applicationId with old package name (with upper litters)

And it work fine, and I uploaded my app to google play successfully.